# Making a link show on click div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with the following page:
http://quakerridgegc.clubhouseonline-e3.com/staging-area/Course-Tour/hole1.aspx

When I click the description it's supposed to show the div `desc-inner-div` ( set the display to `block` from `none`).

I check the console and it gives the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function on line 46.

Following is the code for that page and line 46:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery.noConflict();

$(function(){ (<< ERROR IS HERE)

    //clear value when clicked
    $('.clearme').one("focus", function() {
      $(this).val("");
    });

    //fancybox for infoLinks
    $("a.hole-link").fancybox({
                'width'   :900,
      'height'  :800,
            'type': 'iframe',
      'fitToView' : false,
      'autoSize' : false,
      'autoDimensions' : false
        });


    $(".desc-link").click(function () {

        if ( $(".desc-div").hasClass('open') ) {

            $(".desc-div").removeClass('open').animate({
                'width' : '1000',
                'height' : '1000'   
            }, 1000);

            $(".desc-inner-div").css("display","none");

            } else {    

            $(".desc-div").addClass('desc-div-open').animate({
                'width' : '100%',
                'height' : '100%'   
            }, 1000,  function() {

                $(".desc-inner-div").css("display","block");
            });

            $(".desc-link").css("display","none");
        }   
    }); 

    $(".close-link").click(function () {

        $(".desc-div").animate({
                'width' : '0px',
                'height' : '0px'    
            }, 1000, function() {
                $(".desc-div").removeClass('desc-div-open');
                $(".desc-link").css("display","inline");
            });

        $(".desc-inner-div").css("display","none");

    }); 

}); 
</script>
```

If anyone has any idea, I would love to hear what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you include jQuery before that?

Comment: You need to include jQuery. Also, no point in calling `noConflict()` if you're not going to assign jQuery to a variable other than `$` or reference jQuery directly, i.e. this `jQuery( '.a' )` vs `$( '.a' )`.

Comment: Replace every instances of `$` with `jQuery`. also, make sure you include the jquery lib.

Comment: OP has `jQuery` 3.2.1. Check source.

Comment: Yes i think ihave included it .                                                                  
    <script src="/CMSScripts/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: Simply **remove** `jQuery.noConflict();` -
 this is used to *restore* $ to what it was before jquery was loaded -
 as it was nothing before, it's nothing after. 
 Have a read of what .noConflict does: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 4):

Removing the `noConflict` call should solve your problem:

```
jQuery.noConflict();  // remove this line
```

That method stops jQuery from using the `$` as an alias, which you are doing in your code.

If for some reason you *don't* want jQuery to use the `$` as an alias, keep the `noConflict` call and change all reference to `$` in your code to `jQuery` instead.

Comment: You can also choose something else as a reference to jQuery, i.e. `var jq = jQuery.noConflict();`; Then use `jq` (or whatever) in place of `$`.

Comment: @hungerstar, why on earth would you want to do that when you can simply replace every $ with jQuery in the OP's code and everything will work just fine!

Comment: It's **[an option](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/#entry-examples)** David. That's all, lol. Maybe some prefer a shorthand like `$` instead of writing `jQuery` everywhere. FWIW, I upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

On your web page, in the console, if you type `$`, it says `undefined` indeed. However, `jQuery` is present.

As a simple fix, you can assign `jQuery` to `$` at the beginning of your script :

```
var $ = jQuery;
// now you can start using $
```

A more elaborate way would be to wrap your whole code in a global function, and pass it jQuery :

```
(function($){ // now $ === jQuery
    $(function(){
        // your code here
    )}
)(jQuery)
```

Comment: Hey, mass downvoters, any reason _why_ you're taking me down would be welcome.

Comment: I think you got downvoted because your original answer was a bit pointless. That is, why re-assign jQuery to $? The OP should simply not call `noConflict()` if they're going to do that. The IIFE is a good option.

Comment: I upvoted the answer as this is a valid answer. Don't worry Jeremy, there are countless trigger happy people on STO and most of the time, they don't even know why they have downvoted an answer/question.

Comment: @hungerstar Yeah well, I didn't know what `noConflict()` does. I'm an Angular guy, jQuery is part of my past :)

Comment: `var $` doesn't make sense. Alternate is `jQuery(function($){ ` instead of `$(function...`

Answer (score 0):

If `jQuery.noConflict()` was added by someone else, I would not remove it as it could cause a whole bunch of problems elsewhere.

instead, change all your `$` to `jQuery` so it'll be:

```
jQuery(function() {
```

and so on...

`jQuery.noConflict()` is added on purpose so `$` isn't utilised by it. it's usually to support legacy frameworks like mootools.